# How to implement editable md-select for user's custom value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

There is a `<md-select>` control in Angular Material library. It only allows to select option from list. But what if I want to allow to user to write own value in this field? So I want editable md-select that allows to choose value from list or to write own value. Is it possible?

Comment: not out of the box with that directive, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<md-autocomplete>` instead. See the [demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete).

Comment: I don't see how this is an "Accepted" answer.  The md-autocomplete acts more as a filter to an existing list.  This doesn't allow for the end-user to either 1) select from a list, or 2) type in a new value.  I believe the OP wants the user to "write own value in this field" - which would imply an input field in addition to md-select.  I am in the same situation, and will probably add a checkbox that will display an input field that will have a save behind the scenes to populate the source that the md-select will pull from.

Comment: I think it's a great answer because it's the directive that satisfies the role the user (and I) was looking for.

Comment: An autocomplete is not a select list.  This is a bad workaround, not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Found at https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7970, so the credits go to [icenold](https://github.com/icenold)

```
<style>
    .combocontainer{
        width:200px;
        display:inline;
    }
    .comboinput {
        position:relative;
        top:-3px;
        left:-2.75em;
    }
    .comboinput div._md-text{
        display:none !important;
    }
    .comboinput md-select-value:not([disabled]):focus ._md-select-value{
        border-bottom:none;
    }
    .comboinput md-select-value{
        min-width: 0.0em;
        border-bottom:none !important;
    }
</style>

<div class="combocontainer">
    <md-input-container>
        <label>combobox1</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="chosen"/>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container class="comboinput">
        <md-select ng-model="chosen" md-container-class="combomenu">
            <md-option ng-value="'item 1'">item 1</md-option>
            <md-option ng-value="'item 2'">item 2</md-option>
            <md-option ng-value="'item 3'">item 3</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
<div class="combocontainer">
    <md-input-container>
        <label>combobox2</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="chosen2" />
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container class="comboinput">
        <md-select ng-model="chosen2" md-container-class="combomenu">
            <md-option ng-value="'item 1'">item 1</md-option>
            <md-option ng-value="'item 2'">item 2</md-option>
            <md-option ng-value="'item 3'">item 3</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```